# How to use text in EFI graphic mode?

Tags: c, macos, uefi

I am super new to creating efi application. My aim is to create a small application in efi, that displays some text on a background. But I am stuck with trying to display text on the display (Great would be to have a custom font, but that is not necessary at this stage). I want the app (also) to run on apple systems (to boot from a usb)

1. How do I find good documentation on the EFI functions? It seems super hard to find good examples etc.
2. How can I display a text on a background with EFI?

This is what I got so far. I change the background to a color using the graphics protocol. How do I display a text on it. The Output String doesn't seem to work.

```c
#include "efibind.h"
#include "efidef.h"
#include "efidevp.h"
#include "eficon.h"
#include "efiapi.h"
#include "efierr.h"
#include "efiprot.h"

static EFI_GUID GraphicsOutputProtocolGUID = EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL_GUID;

/**
 * efi_main - The entry point for the EFI application
 * @image: firmware-allocated handle that identifies the image
 * @SystemTable: EFI system table
 */
EFI_STATUS efi_main(EFI_HANDLE image, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *systemTable) {
        EFI_BOOT_SERVICES *bs = systemTable->BootServices;
        EFI_STATUS status;
        EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL *graphicsProtocol;
        SIMPLE_TEXT_OUTPUT_INTERFACE *conOut = systemTable->ConOut;
        EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_MODE_INFORMATION *info;
        UINTN SizeOfInfo, sWidth, sHeight;

        status = bs->LocateProtocol(&GraphicsOutputProtocolGUID, NULL, 
                (void**)&graphicsProtocol);

        if (EFI_ERROR(status) || graphicsProtocol == NULL) {
                conOut->OutputString(conOut, L"Failed to init gfx!\r\n");
                return status;
        }

        conOut->ClearScreen(conOut);

        //Switch to current mode so gfx is started.
        status = graphicsProtocol->SetMode(graphicsProtocol, graphicsProtocol->Mode->Mode);
        if (EFI_ERROR(status)) {
                conOut->OutputString(conOut, L"Failed to set default mode!\r\n");
                return status;
        }

        EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_BLT_PIXEL p;
        p.Red = 200;
        p.Green = 77;
        p.Blue = 13;
        graphicsProtocol->QueryMode(graphicsProtocol, graphicsProtocol->Mode->Mode, &SizeOfInfo, &info);
        sWidth = info->HorizontalResolution;
        sHeight = info->VerticalResolution;
        status = graphicsProtocol->Blt(graphicsProtocol, &p, EfiBltVideoFill, 0, 0, 0, 0, sWidth, sHeight, 0);


while (1) {
conOut->OutputString(conOut, L"Some text that I want to display\r\n");
bs->Stall(500000);
}



        return EFI_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: http://x86asm.net/articles/others/index.html

Comment: Are you talking about EFI (v1.x) or UEFI (v2.x)? When built with EDK2 (UEFI) your code works fine.

Comment: @MiSimon I tried both, it works in an emulator but not to boot from on a mac :/ that is the problem!

Comment: There may be more then one SIMPLE_TEXT_OUTPUT_INTERFACE instances available on your system, use bs->LocateHandleBuffer to get all available handles with SIMPLE_TEXT_OUTPUT_INTERFACE installed and try call OutputString on all instances (use bs->OpenProtocol to get the instance from the handle).

Comment: so I figured out that if I only show text on the mac, I see it, but only very shortly - like a quick flicker and then I it continues to boot into macos... on pc it works fine

Comment: Are you still calling conOut->OutputString in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

UEFI supports graphics output. It also supports text output (which can mean either output to a serial console, or text rendered to a graphical console, or both). But there is no defined way to interact between these in a controlled manner.

Applications that provide a graphical environment with text elements (BIOS configuration menu, GRUB) generally do this using their own frameworks to draw text on the graphical console using GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL.

Comment: On most systems that i have seen the SIMPLE_TEXT_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL is installed at the same handle as the GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL if it is a graphical console and on some other handle if it is a serial, network, etc. console

Comment: @MiSimon: sure, the text console will likely use the graphical console to render, but that makes it more, not less, complicated to interact.

Answer (score 1):

This is a short example of a text renderer using the font module from [LVGL](https://github.com/littlevgl/lvgl/tree/v5.1/lv_misc) (which can be used standalone, replace *#include "../../lv_conf.h"* in the lv_font.h file with *#define USE_LV_FONT_DEJAVU_20 8*) and the Blt method from the GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL

```
#include <Uefi.h>
#include <Library\UefiLib.h>
#include <Protocol\GraphicsOutput.h>
#include "lv_font.h"

#define LETTER_SPACE 2
#define WAIT_SECONDS 10
#define FONT &lv_font_dejavu_20

static EFI_BOOT_SERVICES *gBS;
static EFI_RUNTIME_SERVICES *gRT;
static EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL *gGOP = (EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL *)NULL;
static EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_BLT_PIXEL gWhite = { 255,255,255,0 };

static void _util_render_glyph(UINT32 x, UINT32 y, CHAR8 letter)
{
    UINT32        height;
    UINT32        width;
    UINT32        pm_x;
    UINT32        pm_y;
    UINT32        index;
    const UINT8*  bitmap;
    EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_BLT_PIXEL *pixelmap;

    if (gGOP == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    height = lv_font_get_height(FONT);
    width = lv_font_get_width(FONT, letter);

    // glyph is not defined in this font
    if (width == 0) {
        return;
    }

    bitmap = lv_font_get_bitmap(FONT, letter);

    // using 8 bpp for simplicity
    if (EFI_ERROR(gBS->AllocatePool(EfiLoaderData, height * width * sizeof(*pixelmap), (VOID**)&pixelmap))) {
        return;
    }

    gBS->SetMem((VOID*)pixelmap, height * width * sizeof(*pixelmap), 0);

    // get the current content of the framebuffer to allow 'transparent' blt operations
    gGOP->Blt(gGOP, pixelmap, EfiBltVideoToBltBuffer, x, y, 0, 0, width, height, 0);

    for (pm_y = 0; pm_y < height; pm_y++) {
        for (pm_x = 0; pm_x < width; pm_x++) {
            index = width * pm_y + pm_x;

            if (bitmap[index] > 200) {
                pixelmap[index].Red = 0;
                pixelmap[index].Blue = 0;
                pixelmap[index].Green = 0;
                pixelmap[index].Reserved = 0;
            }
            else if (bitmap[index] > 100) {
                pixelmap[index].Red = 105;
                pixelmap[index].Blue = 105;
                pixelmap[index].Green = 105;
                pixelmap[index].Reserved = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    gGOP->Blt(gGOP, pixelmap, EfiBltBufferToVideo, 0, 0, x, y, width, height, 0);
    gBS->FreePool(pixelmap);
}

static void _util_render_text(UINT32 x, UINT32 y, const CHAR8 *string)
{
    UINT32 index;
    UINTN length;
    UINT32 scr_w;
    UINT32 scr_h;

    UINT32 str_x;

    UINT32 gly_w;
    UINT32 gly_h;

    if (string == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    if (gGOP == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    scr_w = gGOP->Mode->Info->HorizontalResolution;
    scr_h = gGOP->Mode->Info->VerticalResolution;

    length = AsciiStrnLenS(string, 32);

    gly_h = lv_font_get_height(FONT);

    // check if the string can be printed 
    if ((y + gly_h) > scr_h) {
        return;
    }

    if (x > scr_w) {
        return;
    }

    // print the string glyph by glyph
    str_x = x;
    for (index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        // check if the glyph can be printed
        gly_w = lv_font_get_width(FONT, string[index]);
        if ((str_x + gly_w) > scr_w) {
            break;
        }

        // print the glyph
        _util_render_glyph(str_x, y, string[index]);

        // calculate the position of the next glyph
        str_x += gly_w + LETTER_SPACE;
    }
}

static void _util_fill_screen(EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_BLT_PIXEL *color)
{
    if (gGOP == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    gGOP->Blt(gGOP, color, EfiBltVideoFill, 0, 0, 0, 0, gGOP->Mode->Info->HorizontalResolution, gGOP->Mode->Info->VerticalResolution, 0);
}


static void _util_wait(UINT32 seconds)
{
    EFI_TIME    time;
    UINT8       current_second = 255;
    UINT32      elapsed_seconds = 0;

    //wait for some seconds
    while (elapsed_seconds <= WAIT_SECONDS) {
        if (!EFI_ERROR(gRT->GetTime(&time, (EFI_TIME_CAPABILITIES*)NULL))) {
            if (current_second != time.Second) {
                elapsed_seconds++;
                current_second = time.Second;
            }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
        CpuPause();
    }
}

EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI
UefiMain(
    IN EFI_HANDLE        ImageHandle,
    IN EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE  *SystemTable)
{
    EFI_STATUS  eRc;

    gBS = SystemTable->BootServices;
    gRT = SystemTable->RuntimeServices;

    eRc = gBS->LocateProtocol(
        &gEfiGraphicsOutputProtocolGuid,
        NULL,
        (VOID**)&gGOP);

    if (EFI_ERROR(eRc) || gGOP == NULL) {
        return EFI_SUCCESS;
    }

    _util_fill_screen(&gWhite);
    _util_render_text(0, 0, "HELLO WORLD!");

    _util_wait(WAIT_SECONDS);

    return EFI_SUCCESS;
}
```

I tested it on a pc and on a mac it runs on both. Using the tools provided by LVGL on their website you can use any font you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you target MacEFI specifically, you'll need an additional protocol call to force the console into text mode, [like this](https://github.com/acidanthera/OpenCoreShell/blob/master/Patches/legacy-switch-to-text.diff).

Comment: Thanks @CodeRush, I tried, but i am not sure on how to implement it correctly (sorry I am quite new to this), do you know how to implement it on the above example?

Comment: especially with a colored background, I don't know how to make that work

Comment: It's currently unclear what are you trying to achieve at the end, i.e. why do you need a text rendered on background? Graphics in EFI is not easy to do, but there are some project that do it fairly well on both PC and MacOS, like [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net) or [Clover](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cloverefiboot).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What I am trying to do is: Some text on a colored background